# Error in deleting projects in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I tried to delete projects in my PycharmProjects folder, but somehow, Pycharm still recreates the folder after 10 sec. Any help on how I can remove projects from Pycharm?

Comment: Chances are you have a hidden folder for your project remaining. Should be named .idea. Might need to enable hidden files on Windows. Or simply do a "ls -a" in a *nix environment.

Comment: Yeah, my project folder is called "blog". So i went into it, delete the folder called `.idea` and removed the main "blog" folder. But still. it reappears again after 3 sec.