# Pycharm recreate deleted project

Tags: pycharm

I'm using "JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.1 x64" and I had in a project that i wanted to remove from the project viewer, however, I didn't had an option to remove it, so I tried a suggestion I found to rename the project folder.

Doing this caused the project to disappear from the project viewer, however, after 10 seconds, the project reappear and created a folder with the old project name.

Anyone know how I can just remove it without reappearing again?

I found a similar question, but without a working answer [Error in deleting projects in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153657/error-in-deleting-projects-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 1):

From `pycharm`,

GoTo `File` -> `Close project`. This will close the current window project means 
 project in the project viewer and you will be redirected to `home page`

Comment: @rfire: Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: It solve the problem, however, there is only option for closing all opened projects. Since I was running other things in the same time, I had to finish and only after that close. I hoped for a solution that doesn't affect your current work.